# Django admin list_filter duplicate

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates, django-admin-filters

Anyway to use Django's nice "list_filter" feature in other views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interresting external app that allows you to configure filters is [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter). Actually it is way more powerful than django admin list_filter.

> Django-filter is a reusable Django application for allowing users to
>   filter queryset dynamically.  It requires Python 2.4 or higher.  For
>   usage and installation instructions consult the docs directory.
>
> Django-filter can be used for generating interfaces similar to the
>   Django admin's `list_filter` interface.  It has an API very similar
>   to Django's `ModelForms`.  For example if you had a Product model
>   you could have a filterset for it with the code:

```
import django_filters

class ProductFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'price', 'manufacturer']
```

> And then in your view you could do:

```
def product_list(request):
    filterset = ProductFilterSet(request.GET or None)
    return render_to_response('product/product_list.html',
        {'filterset': filterset})
```

> See the [docs](https://github.com/alex/django-filter/tree/master/docs) directory for more information.

There is a really nice API behind the scenes so it's really lots of fun.

Comment: this seems like an excellent solution actually! I'm going to try it out. thanks!